# Access Denied \\domain\sysvol\domain\policies

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

Recently started at a company and I'm trying to perform one of my first admin tasks... Creating a group policy to map a drive for a remote office. I've got the group policy configured but when I go to move my script file from the desktop to the location in Sysvol where it's supposed to go I get an access denied error.

This is a production AD server and I don't really want to go about making changes that are going to bring down AD. Any idea why this would be happening? My account is in the Domain Admins group which is in the Administrators group which has full access to this share.

Comment: Check the filesystem permissions in addition to the share permissions.  What happens when you try to make a change to files there when you're locally logged in to a domain controller, not using the share?

Comment: They're fine on the server itself. I can create/edit files no problem. The problem is definitely on the sysvol share.

Comment: Yeah, so I'm not even sure how to fix this issue. The only account with full access to the Sysvol share is the local system account. Since this is a domain controller there isn't a way to use the Local System credentials to update the permissions on the sysvol share. I have no idea how this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be a member of Domain admins, and Group policy creator owners  group in Active Directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact issue and wasn't able to delete a orphaned GPO in the SYSVOL folders on a couple of my domain controllers, I kept getting access denied taking ownership of the folder didn't help.

As suggested I checked and found I wasn't a member of "Group Policy Creator Owners" once I added my account into it I was able to delete the orphaned GPO.

I think by default you have to explicitly add yourself to this group, as I found only the builtin Administrator was in there, so I just nested the domain admins group in there.

Thanks!